# Fixed header - sliding in animation not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation

First post here since i'm pretty desperate about this one.
So simple, yet it does .. not .. work!

Here it goes:

---

I'm trying to add a sliding down animation to my header once i scrolled past a certain point.
The problem is that the transition does not work, it just "jumps".

**What am I overlooking?**

I set up this **codepen** to keep it as simple as possible to pin down the issue: https://codepen.io/MDVizzy/pen/yLeQRPM

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>THIS REPRESENTS MY HEADER</header>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper { 
  height: 3000px; /* TO SIMULATE SCROLLBAR */
  position: relative; 
}
header { 
  background: red; 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  animation: all 3s;
}
header.animation {
  top: 200px;
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                
                    $("header").addClass('animation');
                
            } else {
                
                $("header").removeClass('animation');
        
            }
    
        });
  
});
```

Comment: Use transition: all 3s; not animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `transition: ...` CSS rule for this code

Using `animation: ...` requires a linked `@keyframes myAnimation { ... }` - [See Mozilla's examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Examples)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                
                    $("header").addClass('animation');
                
            } else {
                
                $("header").removeClass('animation');
        
            }
    
        });
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper { 
  height: 3000px; /* TO SIMULATE SCROLLBAR */
  position: relative; 
}
header { 
  background: red; 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* swap with your `animation: ...` rule */
}
header.animation {
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>THIS REPRESENTS MY HEADER</header>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG, i knew it was something stupid!
I've done it a thousand times so.. :p
Thanks A LOT!

Comment: Haha happens all the time ;p Goodluck! 

Comment: I like answered in a minute and he's thanking you here, lol.

Comment: @VXp , sorry bro, it was my first post on StackOverflow and i overlooked your other comment, it have just seen it, i upvoted it since you guys like that :D